# SpringSecurity gives error 401 Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am new to Spring Security and was creating a simple app to check authentication and authorization. I am using in memory database. Even when I am giving correct login credentials, I am getting error 401 "Bad Credentials" error.
Also I used permitAll() function at some rest endpoints, yet I get a login prompt on those endpoints also. I tried clearing browser history and cache also yet no success. Please help. I am attaching code.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    //Authentication using In Memory Database
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)throws Exception{
        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("{noop}pass123").authorities("ROLE_USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("{noop}pass123").authorities("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN");        
    }

    //Authorization
    @Override //Overriding configure to use HttpSecurity for web based HTTP requests
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)throws Exception{
        httpSecurity.
        authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/protectedbyuserrole*").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/protectedbyadminrole*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/","/notprotected").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();    
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurityApplication.Java**

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.demo","controller"})
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class SpringSecurityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**TestSecurityController.Java**

```
    package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestSecurityController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String Hello() {
        return "Hello World!! ";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/notprotected")
    public String HelloAgain() {
        return "Hello from a non protected user!! ";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/protectedbyuserrole")
    public String HelloUser() {
        return "Hello User Role!! ";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/protectedbyadminrole")
    public String HelloAdmin() {
        return "Hello Admin Role!! ";
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurity-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurity-1</name>
    <description>SpringSecurity for Authentication and Authorization</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**QUERIES**

Also let me know how to use simple passwords which I can use in postman. Should I use {noop} or just simply writing the password like .password("pass123").

Should I use single * or ** asterisk in .antmatchers()

I tried it using Postman also and Firefox also. Same error everywhere.
[POSTMAN SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k2lf.png)

Comment: can you post your pom/build file?

Comment: Please check. I have updated my POM File.

Comment: Additionally to what has been answered, within your Postman screenshot, you used username `user123` and password `pass`, but in your security configuration, you have a username `user` and a password `pass123`, so those don't match either.

Comment: The username and passwords are different beacuse i changed the credentials to check.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. You can remove some code which are not relevant to the question. But please edit it in such a way that it doesn't invalidate the answer provided below. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a particular method (GET, POST etc.) in RequestMapping is a good practice you may need to follow.

I have shared a basic example which I have done in the past.
You can try in the browser with username as myusername and password as a mypassword 
If you still face the problem let me know with your postman screenshot

```
  @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {

            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("myusername")
                .password("mypassword")
                .roles("USER");
        }
```

---

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

             http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/home","/failure").permitAll()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
             .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

---

EDIT

The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:

- ? matches one character
- matches zero or more characters
- ** matches zero or more directories in a path

{spring:[a-z]+} matches the regexp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring"

[Refer Path Matcher Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/protectedbyuser",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String Hello() {
            return "Hello Protected By User!! ";
        }
```

Comment: In the HttpSecurity codeblock (2nd one) should I replace "/user/**" in       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")

with 
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/protectedbyuser/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")

as per my above code logic? I tried to change that way but now i get error 403 access denied instead of error 401 bad credentials. 
Please help as per my program what changes I should make.

Comment: yes, you can write any request name as per your requirement but good practice is to use user.  So now credentials are valid and you are getting 403 Forbidden. Do one thing login with same credentials in your browser instead of postman after successful login try in postman Please share your postman screenshot

Comment: Then I think I need to change the name for my REST endpoints accordingly because currently as you can see from my code, I have added protectedbyuser as an endpoint and not just User. I am just using it for testing purpose. I am unable to add a screenshot here so I am adding the screenshot of postman on the main question. Please check.

Comment: See the edit and log in with your user admin credentials for all access and log in with your user credentials for limited access

Comment: Out of the different antmatcher queries that you wrote, which HTTP method should be used for logging in? GET or POST? I am confused because here we are not posting anything to the DB so no point of POST. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I will prefer the POST method for login. If your login request is via a user supplying a username and password then a POST is preferable, as **details will be sent in the HTTP messages body rather than the URL**. Although it will still be sent plain text unless you're encrypting via https. If you are satisfied with the answer then you can accept the answer.

Comment: I am unable to run it. I think I will go with basic authentication without using Spring security. Can you help me how I can send simple Post Request using Post mapping with parameter to my rest api? Also It will be helpful if I could get your email id. I really need help!

Comment: @KshitizBathwal your problem has nothing to do with paths or methods, stick to spring security and try to remove the prefix Role_ to your authorities and let me know what you get

Comment: yes, you can continue with spring security, if any problem will occur search the issue and you will get solution